# Accessing json elements in Backbone.js Web Application

Tags: json, loops, backbone.js

Apologies if this is a very simple question
The output of 'console.log(content)' is http://grab.by/vSgO
I want to iterate over 'media$group' element at each position. What is the correct way to do so in Backbone.js?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is:

```
for(var i in content.attributes){
    console.log(content.attributes[i].media$group);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better you do it the Backbone way, create a Backbone collection and use the appropriate each method and model.get("media$group")

Answer (score 0):

It seems you should create a collection instead of a model here.

Once you have a collection, you can easily do

```
collection.map(function (model) {
    model.get('media$group');
});
```

to get an array of all the `media$group`s